# Problemas al Iniciar RAD Studio, Embarcadero 10.1

Tags: delphi, delphi-berlin

He Instalado RAD Studio Embarcadero 10.1, y me aparece este error al iniciarlo:

> Aplicación emergente: bds.exe - Error de la aplicación : La aplicación no se pudo iniciar correctamente (0xc000007b). Haga clic en Aceptar para cerrarla.

He Desistalado Visual Studio 2013 y Visual C++ 10, Ademas de Reinstalar el Drive de Direct X.

No encuentro a que mas se pueda deber el error, me urge correr el RAD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno Investigando, RAD Studio requiere el Framework 3.5 y 4.5 de Microsoft para correr sin problemas, Windows 10 no trae por defecto el 3.5.

Windows 10 Home no permite en sus ultimas actualizaciones instalar el Framework, la Única opción es habilitarlo desde **Activar y Desactivar Características de Windows** y luego actualizar, Aunque variaras VPN bloquean el acceso como es mi caso.
Anexo los detalles de los requerimientos: [Requerimientos Técnicos de Instalación](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Installation_Notes)

Por otro lado como yo no puedo descargar el Framework 3.5 por que esta bloqueado en mi red, opte por hacer una virtualización de windows 7 en donde el RAD se instalo sin problemas y puedo ocupar lo sin problemas.
Nota: Tomar en cuenta en la virtualización al menos 70GB de espacio en HDD, en mi caso no me afecta mucho tener una virtualización de ese tamaño a cambio de poder ocupar el RAD, ya que en mi Maquina anfitrión debo utilizar Visual Studio.